# How to remove list elements within a loop effectively in python

Tags: python

I have a code as follows.

```
for item in my_list:
        print(item[0])
        temp = []
        current_index = my_list.index(item)
        garbage_list = creategarbageterms(item[0])

        for ele in my_list:
            if my_list.index(ele) != current_index:
                for garbage_word in garbage_list:
                    if garbage_word in ele:
                        print("concepts: ", item, ele)
                        temp.append(ele)
        print(temp)
```

Now, I want to remove the `ele` from `mylist` when it gets appended to `temp` (so, that it won't get processed in the main loop, as it is a garbage word).

I know it is bad to remove elements straightly from the list, when it is in a loop. Thus, I am interested in knowing if there is any efficient way of doing this?

For example, if `mylist` is as follows;

```
    mylist = [["tim_tam", 879.3000000000001], ["yummy_tim_tam", 315.0], ["pudding", 298.2], 
["chocolate_pudding", 218.4], ["biscuits", 178.20000000000002], ["berry_tim_tam", 171.9], 
["tiramusu", 158.4], ["ice_cream", 141.6], ["vanilla_ice_cream", 122.39999999999999]]
```

**1st iteration**

for the first element `tim_tam`, I get garbage words such as `yummy_tim_tam` and `berry_tim_tam`. So they will get added to my `temp` list.

Now I want to remove `yummy_tim_tam` and `berry_tim_tam` from the list (because they have already added to `temp`), so that it won't execute from the beginning.

**2nd iteration**

Now, since `yummy_tim_tam` is no longer in the list this will execute `pudding`. For `pudding` I get a diffrent set of garbage words such as `chocolate_pudding`, `biscuits`, `tiramu`. So, they will get added to `temp` and will get removed.

**3rd iteration**

`ice_cream` will be selected. and the process will go on.

My final objective is to get three separate lists as follows.

```
["tim_tam", 879.3000000000001], ["yummy_tim_tam", 315.0], ["berry_tim_tam", 171.9] , ["pudding", 298.2]

["chocolate_pudding", 218.4], ["biscuits", 178.20000000000002], ["tiramusu", 158.4]

["ice_cream", 141.6], ["vanilla_ice_cream", 122.39999999999999]
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do with the whole `.index`ing thing. It also seems that `garbage_list` should really be a `set` instead...

Comment: @RoadRunner I want to gather similar words as follows. `["tim_tam", 879.3000000000001], ["yummy_tim_tam", 315.0], ["berry_tim_tam", 171.9]` , `["pudding", 298.2], 
["chocolate_pudding", 218.4], ["biscuits", 178.20000000000002], ["tiramusu", 158.4]` , `["ice_cream", 141.6], ["vanilla_ice_cream", 122.39999999999999]`. I will update the question again :)

Comment: @JCena Are you only trying to remove `yunny_tim_tam` and `berry_tim_tam` from `temp`? Or are their other words your trying to remove? Could you not just add everything and filter out what you don't want at the end of the loop? Or you could have some sort of pre-checking beforehand so you never add them to begin with.

Comment: It is not a good idea to modify lists which are being iterated. Better just check in the main loop if the term is already in temp before processing it. If `True`, `continue`

Comment: @RoadRunner I edited again. I hopeit is clear now :)

Comment: @joaquin it is an interesting suggestion :)

Comment: It is the way to go. If you need to obtain other lists, just create them and fill them appending items inside the for loops as you do for temp, or, if needed, after the main loop is finished. But do not modify mylist during the loops. Use also `enumerate` in the for loops to get the item index. Do not use 8 spaces for indent, just 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code produces what you want:

```
my_list = [['tim_tam', 879.3], ['yummy_tim_tam', 315.0], ['pudding', 298.2],
           ['chocolate_pudding', 218.4], ['biscuits', 178.2], ['berry_tim_tam', 171.9],
           ['tiramusu', 158.4], ['ice_cream', 141.6], ['vanilla_ice_cream', 122.39]
           ]

creategarbageterms = {'tim_tam' : ['tim_tam','yummy_tim_tam', 'berry_tim_tam'],
                      'pudding': ['pudding', 'chocolate_pudding', 'biscuits', 'tiramusu'],
                      'ice_cream': ['ice_cream', 'vanilla_ice_cream']}

all_data = {}
temp = []
for idx1, item in enumerate(my_list):
    if item[0] in temp: continue
    all_data[idx1] = [item]

    garbage_list = creategarbageterms[item[0]]

    for idx2, ele in enumerate(my_list):
        if idx1 != idx2:
            for garbage_word in garbage_list:
                if garbage_word in ele:
                    temp.append(ele[0])
                    all_data[idx1].append(ele)

for item in all_data.values():
    print('-', item)
```

This produces:

```
- [['tim_tam', 879.3], ['yummy_tim_tam', 315.0], ['berry_tim_tam', 171.9]]
- [['pudding', 298.2], ['chocolate_pudding', 218.4], ['biscuits', 178.2], ['tiramusu', 158.4]]
- [['ice_cream', 141.6], ['vanilla_ice_cream', 122.39]]
```

Note that for the purpose of the example I created a mock creategarbageterms function (as a dictionary) that produces the term lists as you defined it in your post. Note the use of a defaultdict which allows unlimited number of iterations, that is, unlimited number of final lists produced.

Answer (score 2):

I would propose to do it like this:

```
mylist = [["tim_tam", 879.3000000000001],   
          ["yummy_tim_tam", 315.0],
          ["pudding", 298.2], 
          ["chocolate_pudding", 218.4], 
          ["biscuits", 178.20000000000002],
          ["berry_tim_tam", 171.9], 
          ["tiramusu", 158.4], 
          ["ice_cream", 141.6], 
          ["vanilla_ice_cream", 122.39999999999999]]

d = set()   # remembers unique keys, first one in wins

for i in mylist:
    shouldAdd = True
    for key in d:
        if i[0].find(key) != -1:    # if this key is part of any key in the set
            shouldAdd = False       # do not add it

    if not d or shouldAdd:          # empty set or unique: add to set
        d.add(i[0]) 

myCleanList = [x for x in mylist if x[0] in d]    # clean list to use only keys in set

print(myCleanList)
```

Output:

```
[['tim_tam', 879.3000000000001], 
 ['pudding', 298.2], 
 ['biscuits', 178.20000000000002], 
 ['tiramusu', 158.4], 
 ['ice_cream', 141.6]]
```

If the order of things in the list is not important, you could use a dictionary directly - and create a list from the dict.

If you need sublists, create them:

```
similarThings = [ [x for x in mylist if x[0].find(y) != -1] for y in d]

print(similarThings)
```

Output:

```
[
    [['tim_tam', 879.3000000000001], ['yummy_tim_tam', 315.0], ['berry_tim_tam', 171.9]], 
    [['tiramusu', 158.4]], 
    [['ice_cream', 141.6], ['vanilla_ice_cream', 122.39999999999999]], 
    [['pudding', 298.2], ['chocolate_pudding', 218.4]], 
    [['biscuits', 178.20000000000002]]
]
```

---

As @joaquin pointed out in the comment, I am missing the `creategarbageterms()` functions that groups `tiramusu` and `biscuits` with `pudding` to fit the question 100% - my answer is advocating "do not modify lists in interations, use appropriate set or dict filter it to the groups. Unique keys here are keys that are not parts of later mentioned keys.

Comment: please note your results do not correspond with the expected output as defined by the OP

Comment: @joaquin Agreed - I am missing the the "broader" `creategarbageterms()` function that makes biscuits and tiramusu belong the the pudding variety. The question evolved quite a bit and my answer was build with less data than there is now. The `creategarbageterms()` is still not in the question and your answer approximated it from the "later added" information as to what 3 results should be given. Your answer is better suited to answer the `How to remove list elements within a loop effectively in python` - mine is "how to get to the result without modifying iteration in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have an outer loop that's looping through a list, and an inner loop that can modify that same list.

I saw you got suggestions in the comments to simply not remove entries during the inner loop at all, but instead check if terms already are in `temp`. This is possible, and may be easier to read, but is not necessarily the best solution with respect to processing time.

I also see you received an answer from Patrick using dictionaries. This is probably the cleanest solution for your specific use-case, but does not address the more general question in your title which is specifically about removing items in a list while looping through it. If for whatever reason this is really necessary, I would propose the following:

```
idx = 0
while idx < len(my_list)
    item = my_list[idx]
    print(item[0])
    temp = []
    garbage_list = creategarbageterms(item[0])

    ele_idx = 0
    while ele_idx < len(my_list):
        if ele_idx != idx:
            ele = my_list[ele_idx]
            for garbage_word in garbage_list:
                if garbage_word in ele:
                    print("concepts: ", item, ele)
                    temp.append(ele)
                    del my_list[ele_idx]
        ele_idx += 1
    print(temp)
    idx += 1
```

The key insight here is that, by using a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop, you can take more detailed, ''manual'' control of the control flow of the program, and more safely do ''unconventional'' things in your loop. I'd only recommend doing this if you really have to for whatever reason though. This solution is closer to the literal question you asked, and closer to your original own code, but maybe not the easiest to read / most Pythonic code.

Comment: @JohnKugelman yes I know, that was the entire point of the answer, because this is a requirement of the question if we read the question's title literally. If you meant to point out that this means the second loop should also be a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop, that's correct, I missed that and just edited to fix that